# This program might not have run correctly

Tags: .net, windows

Each time I build an exe and then execute it for the first time, I get a warning from Windows after exiting the program saying: "This program might not have run correctly." and gives me the option to just say it actually executed OK or to run the program in compatibility mode. What I would like to know is what is triggering Windows to think that the program might not have run correctly.

This EXE calls a registered .NET dll using COM, by the way.

Take into consideration that this problem is different to "This program might not have INSTALLED correctly", which has to do with the setup or installation, not with executing a regular exe.

Comment: Please post your code - particularly the code using the COM dll

Comment: More than reviewing the code, what I would like to know is what Windows checks or validates that triggers this behavior.